# Cannot promisify an API that has normal methods with 'Async'-suffix

Tags: node.js, soap, promise

I am trying to call soap web service using node. I have used soap and request packages.

Below is the code snippet :

```
var express = require('express');
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var app = express();
var soap = require('soap')

var url = 'http://example.com?WSDL';
let request = require('request');
let request_with_defaults = request.defaults({
  'proxy': 'http://example.com:80',
  'timeout': 5000,
  'connection': 'keep-alive'
});
let soap_client_options = {
  'request': request_with_defaults
};
var args = {
  requestId: '1406303'
};
soap.createClient(url, soap_client_options, function(err, client) {
  var soapHeader = {
    "Username": "test",
    "Password" : "test"
  };
  client.addSoapHeader(soapHeader);

  client.getESSJobStatus(args, function(err, result) {
    if(err){
      console.log('Error occured');
    }
    console.log(result);
  });
})
```

here i am getting error :

```
throw new TypeError("Cannot promisify an API that has normal methods with '%s'-suffix\u000a\u000a    See http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/error-explanations.htmlX\u000a"
TypeError: Cannot promisify an API that has normal methods with 'Async'-suffix
See http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/error-explanations.html
```

I have checked this url. it is saying  that async task gets created which is not able to call. But i am not able to relate this.

can anyone help me with code how can i resolve this issue?

Comment: `it is saying that async task gets created` no it isn't - and there's no hint of Promisify in the code you posted

Comment: perhaps read the "soap" docs *`overridePromiseSuffix: if your wsdl operations contains names with Async suffix, you will need to override the default promise suffix to a custom one, default: Async`* - https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap

Comment: try adding `overridePromiseSuffix: 'Blah'` or whatever to your `soap_client_options`

Comment: can you give me some code?

Comment: i am not getting anything for make this code working.

Comment: what have you tried since I suggested something? e.g. `let soap_client_options = {
  'request': request_with_defaults, overridePromiseSuffix: 'Blah'
};` .... same error?

Comment: `let soap_client_options = { 'request': request_with_defaults, overridePromiseSuffix: 'getESSJobStatus' };`

this is giving me same error

Comment: well, that's odd, because you're not trying to use the `Async` suffix anymore - seems like something is broken

Comment: Of course, the funniest thing about your code is that you aren't even trying to use the Promisified functions!

Comment: how to promisify the code?

Comment: the `soap` library you are requiring already does that for you, that's where the error is coming from most likely, when it tries to promisify the soap methods described in the WSDL, I presume

Comment: oh, do you mean how to use the promisified versions ... well, you wont have much like until you fix this problem

Answer (score 1):

Try `Promise.promisifyAll(require('soap'), {suffix: 'MySuffix'});`